# Changing a list to int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely stumped on how to change a list to an int.

```
#Creates a list which is populated by whole names and scores
    whole_names = list()
    scores = list()

    for line in lines:
        # Makes each word a seperate object
        objects = line.split(" ")
        # Joins the first and last name of every line and makes them 
          their own seperate objects
        whole_names.append(" ".join(objects[0:2]))
    # Makes the scores of every line an object
        scores.append(objects[2:3])

rect = Rectangle(Point(2, y-50), Point(scores[0],y-25))
rect.setFill("darkgreen")
rect.draw(win)
```

The problem is, the Point(scores[0], y-25)) wont fill because scores[0] is a list, not an int, so it technically cant be a coordinate, but the actual value of scores[0] in that list is going to be some random number, I don't know what number it will be, but it will in fact be an integer. So how do I turn scores[0] into the random integer? I've tried
scores = int(scores) but that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `scores[0]` is something like `['10']`:

```
Point(int(scores[0][0]), y-25)
```

However, this not the right solution. To make it better, change this line:

```
scores.append(objects[2:3])
```

Which return a sequence, to this:

```
scores.append(objects[2])
```

Which returns the item itself. With this, you'll only have to convert it to integer straight away:

```
Point(int(scores[0]), y-25)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     scores.append(objects[2:3])
> ```

This line gives you a 1-element sequence, which is probably not what you want. Index instead of slicing.

```
    scores.append(objects[2])
```